# parse error in haskell <-

Tags: haskell

```
--bmicalculator
bmicalculator::IO()
bmicalculator=do bmicalculator::(RealFloat a)=>a->a->String
putStrLn "Please Input your weight"
weight<-getLine
putStrLn "Please Input your height"
height<-getLine
|bmi<=17.5="You are anorexia!"
|bmi<=20.7="You are Under weight"
|bmi<=26.4="You are in normal range"
|bmi<=27.8="You are marginally overweight"
|bmi<=31.1="You are overweight"
|bmi>31.1="You are super OBESE!!"
where bmi=weight/height^2
```

the error happened in

```
weight<-getLine
```

how could i prompt user to input "weight" and "height" then calculate and return string like what i create the datatype `bmicalculator::(RealFloat a)=>a->a->String`

Comment: you could read [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Learn_Haskell_in_10_minutes) in less time than you needed to type the question

Comment: i know the way of achieve the calculation and the result.
but i want do it the way of passing 2 float value and return a string value, rather than if else or case statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

additionally you want to separate the bmi-calculator from the main function as it is a pure function without any side-effects

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Please Input your weight"
    w <- getLine
    let weight = read w :: Float
    putStrLn "Please Input your height"
    h <- getLine
    let height = read h :: Float
    putStrLn $ bmicalc weight height

bmicalc :: Float -> Float -> String
bmicalc weight height | bmi<=17.5 = "You are anorexic!"
                      | bmi<=20.7 = "You are underweight"
                      | bmi<=26.4 = "You are in normal range"
                      | bmi<=27.8 = "You are marginally overweight"
                      | bmi<=31.1 = "You are overweight"
                      | otherwise = "You are super OBESE!!"
                      where bmi=weight/(height*height)
```

Comment: yeah please consider an upvote if it helped, and try to read a lot of haskell code from people who really know it - there is a stackoverflow question about haskell style.

Answer (score 3):

First of all your indentation is wrong (which is to say: non-existent). The contents of the do-block should be indented.

Then you gave two type signatures that don't match each other to bmicalculator. The second one is inside the do-block where it clearly does not belong.

Then you seem to be using pattern-guards inside the do-block, outside of any pattern matching construct. This is syntactically invalid. You're probably missing a `case bmi of` there. You also need to replace `=` with `->`.

Lastly you can't use variables which are local to the do-block inside a where-block that comes after the `do`-block. You should use a `let` inside the `do`-block instead. Furthermore `weight` and `height` are string, so you can't do arithmetic on them without converting them to numbers first.

Comment: thanks for the help, because there is less material on the internet about haskell, i tried to combine different tutorial, therefore i'm getting some syntax error. I'm still a beginner of haskell..

Comment: i want to ask how to declare less than in the case statement?
case bmi of
    |bmi<=17.5="You are anorexia!"
i tried like this, but "|"having error"
or <=17.5 still having error

Comment: While you can simulate guards using `case` (i.e. `case () of _ | bmi <= 17.5 -> doStuff`, I suggest you to extract this part into pure function, something like [this](http://ideone.com/K2ASA)